# How to create per-process variables in a kernel module?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

#### Scenario

I'm implementing a simple IPC system in linux kernel. To simply the question, assume we only have 2 system calls. and the interface *cannot* be changed.

1. `SYSCALL_DEFINE1(add, int, id)`
2. `SYSCALL_DEFINE1(del, int, id)`

if `add` has an existing element with `id`, then it needs to report 'already exist', `EEXIST`.

So I thought it needs to store the added data somewhere. My choice is to store it inside my syscall implementation `.c` file, as a global value. Like:

```
struct mylist {
    int id;
    struct list_head list;
};

LIST_HEAD(id_list);

SYSCALL_DEFINE1(add, int, id) {
    // kmalloc struct mylist
    // operate on `id_list` (add, check existence)
}
```

#### Problem

When I write a user space program to have a test.

- The first time I ran the test it is ok.
- The second time it fails, because it reports `id already exists`!

The memory does not appear as I thought.

#### Questions

1. What is the lifetime of kernel space data `id_list`? (as long as the system is up?)
2. How can I make `id_list`'s lifetime equal to userspace program?

Comment: 1. yes. 2. natively nohow, probably you better reconsider the design.  Still can't get it - what are you trying to achieve by this?

Comment: @AlexHoppus, it is course project, the interface can not be changed.